# Jquery .hover displaying all arrow glyphicons in li tags that is inside foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm a bit confused on how to properly insert my `.hover()` function inside my foreach `li` tags. cause when ever I hover my cursor on the assigned class all of the tags displays the `glyphicon` content.

here is my code.

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery(".side-nav").hover(function() {

    jQuery('.hover-arrow-right').show();

  });

});
```

```html
<nav class="side-nav">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($posts as $p): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p->ID);?>">
      <li>
        <?php echo $p->post_title; ?><span class="hover-arrow-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </li>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the proper output is the glyphicon must only show when the cursor is placed on a li respectively.

sorry for my bad english.

thank you. hope anyone can help me in my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do hover on the li

```
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery(".side-nav ul a > li").hover(function() {

    jQuery(this).find('.hover-arrow-right').show();

 });

});
```

Comment: `jQuery('this')` should be `jQuery(this)`

Comment: what's the result on debug console ?